# Redirect interface to object

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, interface

I want to make a few extensions to a class that is not visible. I only have its interface.

I'm creating a class:

```
public class MyClass implements TheirInterface {
    private TheirObject o;
    public MyClass(TheirObject o) {
        this.o = o;
    }
}
```

I'm implementing `TheirInterface`, it contains a large amount of abstract methods. `TheirObject` also implements `TheirInterface`. I want to redirect all of its methods to `o`.

So instead of manually writing all methods..

```
@Override
public boolean theirBoolean() {
    return o.theirBoolean();
}

@Override
public String theirString() {
    return o.theirString();
}

@Override
public void theirVoid(String s) {
    o.theirVoid(s);
}
```

Is there a way to generate the code?

Comment: If you just have the interface then no. You have to add the code for it. Interfaces you say what methods will exist, not what they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Eclipse:**

Select `o` and left click, go to Source - Generate delegate methods..